# show that there exists a unique solution to the boundary value problem $(3-2e^{-x})u''+(\frac{1}{2000}+e^{-x})u=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

show that there exists a unique solution to the boundary value problem $(3-2e^{-x})u''+(\frac{1}{2000}+e^{-x})u=0$ for $0\le x \le 4$ with $u(0)=u(4)=0$.

I tried to look at the homogeneous ODE $u''+\frac{\frac{1}{2000}+e^{-x}}{3-2e^{-x}}u=0$ and bound it from above with an ODE of the form $u''+r(x)u=0$ with a constant $r(x)=1+\frac{1}{2000}$, so that I get the solution $u_*=sin(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2000}}x)$. if this solution doesn't vanish on the interval [0,4] then the only solution of the original ODE is the trivial solution, but $u_*$ has a zero at $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2000}}}\le4$ so I'm not sure what to do next, do I need to bound the ODE with a non-constant $r(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set $y=u'$, then you problem becomes $$\begin{pmatrix}u\\y\end{pmatrix}'= \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&\frac{1/2000+e^{-x}}{3-2e^{-x}}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}u\\ y\end{pmatrix}.$$
and use [Picard-Lindelof theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: It's a boundary value problem not an initial value problem

Comment: @SlyxBrd: Picard-Lindelof theorem applies to your question.